# Display both standard posts in a specific category along with a custom post type in a single loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm building a content slider that needs to show posts from a custom post type called "Features," and also show standard blog posts that are assigned to a "Featured" category. I'd like to do this within a single loop. Can anyone help me put together the query that could handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts( array(
        'post_type' => array(
                    'post',
                    'features',

                ),
'category_name' => 'Featured',
                'paged' => $paged )

            );

// have some posts?
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        // the loop

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: you can also use `'posts_per_page' => -1` to display all posts

Comment: Works great! However, this query assumes that the custom post type will also be of the category 'Featured'. I solved this by enabling the default categories for the custom post type as well so I can assign them to the 'featured' category. For future reference, is there a way around that within this query?

Comment: By default Wordpress assumes AND on SELECT queries. To use OR you'll need to use custom SELECT [Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Answer (score 0):

Fix paging issues:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Query to add in custom post types:

```
query_posts( array(
        'post_type' => array(
                    'post',
                    'custom_post_type_name'
                ),
                'paged' => $paged ) 
            );
```

Start the main loop

```
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

            //Post content

    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```